# Make bitmap shake like that

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a bitmap of bird flying from point a straight to point b, and I want to make the movement a bit more natural, with some wiggles and small random movements that are smooth and not jittery, I'm using canvas so I can't use xml, but is there something automatic that can add some natural shakes to the bitmap while it is moving like animator?

Something like that:
[image]

My first idea was getting random points around the bitmap and moving it towards them, but that would look very robotic and not smooth, is there some calculation I can do to make the movement between points smoother?

I will also be happy to hear other ideas of creating a wiggle effect, any idea will help because I cant think of anything, nor find anything.

Here is the flying code:

```
public void fly(float x1,float y1,float scale){
    flyTo.x=x1;
    flyTo.y=y1;
    this.scale=scale;
    mCurrentState=BossState.Flying;
}
private void UpdateAll(){
switch (mCurrentState) {
case Flying:
    if(flyTo.x==position.x&&flyTo.y==position.y){
        mCurrentState=BossState.Normal;
    }
    else{
        if(flyTo.x>position.x){
            position.x+=speed;
        }
        else if(flyTo.x<position.x){
            position.x-=speed;
        }
        if(flyTo.y>position.y){
            position.y+=speed;
        }
        else if(flyTo.y<position.y){
            position.y-=speed;
        }
    }
    break;
...
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, depending on the "scale" of the problem (are we close to the bird? Is it just some background feature?), I would rather focus on making the whole flight more natural. E.g., it could have a curve path rather than a straight one, a modulated velocity, you could make it slow down when landing to B, ...

Comment: @miav The bird is in the background, but I want to enable this wiggle effect on floating monsters for example and more things like text and so on. How can I make a curve path? ill update the question with the flying code